# I need to loop a section of HTML code with php/javascript, suggestions?

Tags: php, javascript, html, loops

I've attempted using a for loop and heredoc in php using similar code:

```
 $options = ''; 

for($Year = date("Y"); $Year <= date("Y") + 5; $Year++) 
{ $options .= "<option>$Year</option>\n"; } 

$Select = <<<QQxQQ 
<select> 
$options 
</select> 
QQxQQ; 


print "$Select";
```

But no luck...

**EDIT**
These examples are great, thanks guys.
This is what I'm trying to iterate

```
<li><a href="#"><span>$looped</span></a></li>
```

Where *$looped* is a value of a fetched mysql column. As you can probably see, I'm trying to iterate an element of a list x amount of times (where x = number of rows of sql query).

I thought trying to put the results into an array and then cycling through the array, however I still couldn't get the HTML code to go through the parser accordingly without being considered a string.

Comment: Is it necessary that you want to use heredoc?

Comment: The interpreter is complaining about a whitespace after your heredoc declaration, otherwise it's fine - [test](http://codepad.org/sAkIjWPV)

Comment: Based on the update you posted, try this then [Echoing mysqli queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806998/echoing-mysqli-queries)

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
<select>
<?php
    for($Year = date("Y"); $Year <= date("Y") + 5; $Year++) {
        echo "<option>".$Year."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<?php

$year = date('Y');
$end = ($year + 5);
do {
    $option .= '<option>'.$year.'</option>';
} while (++$year <= $end);

echo '<select>'.$option.'</select>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Heredocs have their place, but imo they are overrated and often used in the wrong context.

Try this:

```
$year = date("Y");
for( $Year = $year; $Year <= ($year+5); $Year++ ) { 
    $options .= "<option value=\"$Year\">$Year</option>\n"; 
}

echo "<select name='years' id='years'>";
echo $options;
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<?php
for($Year = date("Y"); $Year <= date("Y") + 5; $Year++) 
{ echo "<option>$Year</option>\n"; } 
?>
</select>
```